# Step 6 in Elfenland

Tags: elfenland

In Elfenland, it states that on step 6, all the transport counters that were placed on the map are to be removed and shuffled with the remaining face down counters.

Should I understand from this, that the map will never be completely filled with counters?
If that is indeed correct, then if 4 players are in separate regions and have no way of interacting directly and no interest, can you only use your few counters to move around your position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the Transportation Counters are removed at the end of the turn, but all players play out the Transportation Counters before the movement phase starts.  In the movement phase, you can use the counters that other players have played onto routes.  If the players start the turn isolated from each other, it seems likely that a successful tactic would be to move towards and make good use of the Transportation Counters laid by another player!